# Gremlin-Go: Tree Step Is Not Serializable

Tags: go, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am running a query to traverse all the "in" edges following a specific label, and I will be doing a similar query later for the "out" edges later. I want to get this as a tree as there may be a vertex with multiple edges to traverse and need to reflect that in my client, so I can't just use a `ToList()` here.

I'm currently using Gremlin-Go SDK, but when calling the `Tree()` step I get a deserialization error. Here's a snippet from my client code:

```golang
    res, err := g.V(id).
        Emit().
        Repeat(__.In(label)).
        Tree().
        Next() // Other terminal steps produce same issue
```

This produces the deserialization error on the data type `0x2b`, which is a [GraphBinary core data type "Tree"](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.6.2/dev/io/#_core_data_types)

```
2023/02/28 12:23:05 Error occurred during operation gremlinServerWSProtocol.readLoop(): 'E0408: unknown data type to deserialize 0x2b'
2023/02/28 12:23:05 Read loop error 'E0408: unknown data type to deserialize 0x2b', closing read loop.
2023/02/28 12:23:05 Connection error callback invoked, closing protocol.
```

The Gremlin-Go reference docs don't seem to mention anything on specific serialization support. According to the `gremlin-go` [README](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/gremlin-go/v3.5.4/gremlin-go#supported-data-types), it supports all core GraphBinary data types. I have tested my query in Gremlin Console to verify the query and server:
`g.V(<ID>).emit().repeat(__.in(<LABEL>)).tree().next()`.

---

For some added context, I am developing this against `gremlin-server:3.5.3` locally for experimentation with the intention of finalizing queries with support for AWS Neptune. I'm aware these aren't fully interchangeable and will follow the [Neptune-Gremlin reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html#feature-gremlin-applicable-standards). The latest version of Neptune specifies the latest supported version of Gremlin is 3.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, only the Java (and other JVM based clients) are able to de-serialize structures like a SubGraph or a Tree. This is because those are the only Gremlin clients that have native implementations of those data structures currently available (for example the JVM clients have TinkerGraph available).

This is an item that the TinkerPop community is very aware of and it is on the list of things that it makes sense to improve.

A possible workaround (not a great one) is to use the HTTP endpoint (sending queries as text) and processing the GraphSON returned if getting this type of data structure back is essential.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. Going through the source code for `gremlin-go`, I do see the support for Tree type is missing despite the implication it was. 

For the solution to my issue, I will see if there are other steps I can use to try avoid using the GraphSON / HTTP route. It also looks feasible for me to instead call the steps `g.V(<ID>).emit().repeat(__.in(<LABEL>)).path()`  and process each result on the client side to build the model I need.

Comment: I think if you can make `path` work that is a better solution than falling back on HTTP.

Comment: I was indeed able to get the `Path()` step working and build a tree-like structure (a struct with a self-referencing map of maps) on the client side. Basically for each `Next()` path object, follow each existing vertex in the tree with a cursor and insert the last vertex at the cursor position.